# Individual Regex matching for 2 similar expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have 2 regexes that share the same first half. The second regex has additional parameters that are a param and number.

First Regex: `/\/param1\/param2\/param3/`
Second Regex `/\/param1\/param2\/param3\?additionalParam=([0-9]+)/`

I choose to compare different values against these regexes which I have placed in a config file and loop over. If they match then it returns a value.

When I run a list of values against them, the first regex always returns and the second one never returns as it matches the input value on the first regex and never reaches the second to compare.

for example:

```
string1: 'param1/param2/param3'  //returns on Regex1 
string2: 'param1/param2/param3?additionalParam=123456'  //still returns on Regex1 because it matches the first part.
```

How do I match on them individually so I get the right return value?

Comment: Your second string **correctly** is matched by the first regular expression because it contains the pattern. If you want, you can anchor the pattern with `^` at the start (to anchor to the beginning of the test string) or `$` at the end (to anchor to the end of the test string).

Comment: Can you reverse the order of the checks?

Answer (score 0):

Does changing your first regex to `/\/param1\/param2\/param3$/` solve your problem?